# PHP - Instead of doing ECHO's to debug variable values, how to send the value to a file?

Tags: php, logging

I need to debug an Application, but the ECHO $variable it is not working.

How can I send the value of the variable to a log file?

Give me some clues.

Best Regards,

Comment: what do you mean by "it's not working"? if $variable is boolean, then try var_dump($variable) instead of echo

Answer (score 5):

[trigger_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) in combination with [error_reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) allows you to easily log what you want on development servers, without worrying about the load on your production servers.

It adds more information than error_log:

```
trigger_error('foo');
```

results in

```
[Fri Apr 08 14:28:08 2011] [error] [client 192.168.0.13] PHP Notice:  foo in /data/sites/kai/public_html/foo.php on line 3
```

whereas `error_log('foo');` results in

```
[Fri Apr 08 14:28:08 2011] [error] [client 192.168.0.13] foo
```

Answer (score 4):

```
file_put_contents('/path_to_file/file.txt', print_r($variable, true));
```

OR

```
file_put_contents('/path_to_file/file.txt', var_export($variable, true));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 error_log('some variable');
```

But the value of variable will be the same in log file. You must have some error above it.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think this approach is wrong. You will clutter your code with either echo statements or functions to write to a file. This has a huge maintainability cost as you have to add/remove these statements.

I recommend that you learn how to step into your code and debug using `xdebug`. It's the only solution that I usually recommend for people trying to see how values for a certain variable is changing during execution time.

With that said, and if you still prefer the writing to file method, then simply instead of doing an echo statement do something like the following:

```
$file = "log.txt";
$fh = fopen($file, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $variableName);
fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm with @Ali on this one. But you could always try [FirePHP](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firephp/), it allows you to write logging information to their library and then see it much like you would normally with [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/). Here is a small tutorial too - http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/php/debugging-php-with-firebug-and-firephp-365/ .